# TFS 2010 API Resources

Tags: tfs-sdk

Does anyone have any good resources for working with the TFS 2010 API?  I specifically looking at how to create, read, update and delete work items.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please see the [Team Foundation Server 2010 SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk) on MSDN Code Gallery. More content will be coming on-line for the RTM release, but you should find enough there to get you started. [Contact me](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/contact.aspx) know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Jim, will do.  We're just about ready to move all developers to TFS 2010.  There's a number of projects we're also going to tie into TFS, it's going to be great!

Answer (score 9):

- [Shai Ratan's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/tags/TFS+API/default.aspx) has a huge wealth of examples. They're 2008 but 99% still relevant.
- [www.tfsexamples.com](http://www.tfsexamples.com) has 2008 examples, but still relevant
- [WorkItemManager class](http://hg.shrinkrays.net/spruce/src/b9ee91ead1c0/Spruce.Core/Domain/Managers/WorkItemManager.cs) from a TFS OS project I'm currently working on called [Spruce](http://hg.shrinkrays.net/spruce), which is ASP.NET MVC 3 front end for TFS workitems. The class illustrates a large portion of what you need, although no deleting examples. `WorkItemSummary` in that class is simply a scaled down `WorkItem` object.
- [BacklogItemHandler](http://scrumdashboard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61724#1080856) from the [Scrum Dashboard project](http://scrumdashboard.codeplex.com/) on codeplex also has a lot of good examples of how to use the API.

Comment: +1 for the links Chris, thanks.  Don't suppose you know if/where tfsexamples.com migrated to and if there are any new good resources now TFS2010 has been out a while?  Cheers!

Comment: @Smudge202 what do you need to know? Most of the stuff on that wiki was fairly basic

Comment: WorkItemManager link not working.Can you please suggest an updated one?