# How to update Create By Field of a workItem in Tfs 2010 with t-sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We migrated from TFS2008 to TFS2010.  In TFS2008, we used the query below to update our workitems in the SQL Server database for TFS, but in the new TFS2010 database, I don't know how to do it.

This is my query that worked in TFS2008

```
update dbo.WorkItemsLatest set [Created By] = @CreatedBy where ID = @id
update dbo.WorkItemsAre set [Created By] = @CreatedBy where ID = @id
```

What is the query performs the same operation in TFS2010?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: So what is the problem using that query in tfs 2010 ?? Do you get an error - if so : please post the **exact and complete** error you're getting! Aren't those possible changes in database structure documented somewhere in the TFS documentation?? Have you searched them for this information??

Answer (score 1):

The query should work as the table names have not changed. However, TFS 2010 introduces the concept of collections which probably breaks the query in regards to the *database* name. So just make sure you're querying the correct database. E.g:

```
use Tfs_DefaultCollection
```

**A word of advice:** It's a very bad practice to modify the TFS database directly. Always prefer the [TFS API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944689/147211) as your first choice of approach whenever the standard customization doesn't suit your requirements.

Comment: Not only is it a bad practice, the product team does not support this in any way you can be refused support from Microsoft's Product Support Services.