# Team Foundation Server 2010 API

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good site showing examples of using TFS 2010's API.

I would like to develop a project that would allow a team to see which files/items other team members had checked out. It simply a system users could see which projects developers are currently working on. Does any one have any experience with this that could give advise to get started?

I would be developing in .NET (C# OR VB) and the application would ride on a SQL Server 2008 database.

Comment: Why not just use http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ instead?

Comment: Have you tried MSDN for starters?

Comment: I hope you are aware that you can use the Team Explorer window within Visual Studio to see what other team members are working on.

Comment: I am aware of this but it is not easy to see a large picture with many projects and developers

Comment: On the general "TFS 2010 API resources": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944689/tfs-2010-api-resources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Alex mentions, TFS Sidekicks from Attrice has this functionality.

In addition, the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) allows you to use "Find in Source Control" to see what files are checked out by any (or all) users.

However, if you did want to roll your own solution, you could do so pretty easily using the [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  I'll let the documentation speak for itself, but you'll probably want to do something along the lines of:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
VersionControlServer vc = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

/* Get all pending changesets for all items (note, you can filter the items in the first arg.) */
PendingSet[] pendingSets = vc.GetPendingSets(null, RecursionType.Full);

foreach(PendingSet set in pendingSets)
{
    /* Get each item in the pending changeset */
    foreach(PendingChange pc in set.PendingChanges)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pc.ServerItem + " is checked out by " + set.OwnerName);
    }
}
```

(Note: totally untested)

But again, I'd recommend you check out those two existing projects to see if they fit your needs.

Comment: +1 for showing a concrete argument for the project collection in a Uri. I didn't find this on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

TFS Sidekicks by Attrice already does this and a lot more. Plus, it's free

[TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)