# Visual Studio Team Services API

Tags: tfs, sdk, azure-devops

Does anyone know if there is a Visual Studio Team Services (http://visualstudio.com/) API? Please note I am referencing the "Service" and not the "Server".

I've been looking but I have been unable to find one.

Comment: AFAIK, it's a subset of the server API.

Comment: Team Foundation Service is simply an Azure-hosted version of Team Foundation Server.  Thus the Team Foundation Server API is the same, whether you use on-premises TFS or the hosted Team Foundation Service.  Is there something concrete you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS 2010 API Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944689/tfs-2010-api-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does provide REST ful as well as Client Object Model (DLL) based APIs which works both for on-premise Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Team Services. But, REST ful API is still not complete, for example, there is still no end-point for getting drop-down field values. It is therefore recommended to use COM DLL APIs.

Answer (score 4):

See: [Team Foundation Server OData API](https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/)

Have a read, then follow the instructions from "**Team Foundation Service authentication:**" to set up your account/profile to access the Api.

You can then access the resources via the web Api.

There are also some sample applications near the top of that page that make use of this Api/OData.

Answer (score 1):

As Edward and Christopher pointed out, the Client Object Model for the Cloud version of TFS and the on-premise version are identical, but not all API's will work with both systems. You can download the Client Object Model installer from the following location:

- [2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa)
- [2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75) and [Forward Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

Which API's work on which system is constantly changing, since new features are added to the cloud version all the time, while certain features are currently only available on the on-premise version (sharepoint integration and reporting for example).

Apart from that there is an OData API for TFS 2010 on-premise and that API is expected to be released for TFSvc and TFS on-premise in the near future. Probably coming to the TFSvc first.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server now also has REST APIs, service hooks, and an extensions framework:

https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/overview